# How to update cpq QLE from CPQ External Configurator?

Tags: cpq

Requirement:
The requirement is that we need to popup an external page on quote line editor via custom action. In external page, we will generate new quotelines by customized logic.

Problems:
We followed cpq plugin doc and it mentioned we need to use postMessage of easyXDM to send JSON data to interact with QLE. But the doc doesn't mention any details about JSON data format.

Does anyone know how to update QLE via external configurator page? Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Have you tried adding few Quote Line Items to any of the existing quotes, and seeing the quote JSON in your external configurator?